# C# - sum and average of 10 read numbers with do-while loop?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm writing a program that takes 10 numbers from the user (Console Application), creates the sum and average of those numbers and outputs the sum and average.

I was able to do this with a for loop but don't know how to transfer the same logic to a do while loop.

```
int sum, i, n;
sum = 0;
double avg;

Console.Write("Input the 10 numbers : ");
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    Console.Write("Number-{0} :",i);

    n= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());     
    sum +=n;
}
avg=sum/10.0;
Console.Write("The sum of 10 numbers is : {0}\nThe Average is : {1}\n",sum,avg);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And what did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sum = 0, i = 0, n = 0;
double avg = 0.0d;

Console.Write("Input the 10 numbers : ");

do
{
    Console.Write("Number-{0} :", i);
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());     
    sum += n;
    ++i;
} while(i < 10);

avg = sum / 10.0;

Console.WriteLine($"The sum of 10 numbers is : {sum}\nThe Average is : {avg}");
```

Tested using [online C# runner (rextester)](http://rextester.com/REE29144).